# Netbeans Error in Java Hello World Program

Tags: java, netbeans

I just downloaded Netbeans and wrote this hello world program.

```
package demo;
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }  
}
```

The output is;

```
run:
Bissmilah
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I don't understand the 3rd line there.

**Update:**
I complied using `javac` and was prompted

`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
So, apparently, its not IDE, or is it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683715/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message

Comment: Sorry, you cannot see that closed question - see here instead http://superuser.com/questions/585695/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message

Comment: @fvu I am new to java, so need assistance as to where does that line of code go? Thank you

Comment: It's not an error, it's a diagnostic message from the java executable, which you can just ignore. If it annoys you, check out the linked question to see how to get rid of it.

Comment: Also see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414699/picked-up-java-options-when-no-such-environment-variable-exists It's related to _JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: This doesn't actually look like an error?