# "Picked up _java_options" message when installing application, but no envrironment variable is set

Tags: java, installation, jvm, java-opts

I'm using an exe file to install an application, but am running into a weird issue. When installing, I get a "Picked up _java_options" followed by a gibberish value with seemingly random characters. This leads to an error where the JVM for the application cannot be created.

The _java_options environment variable is not not set. In addition, I searched the files of the application and could not find any reference to _java_options.

I saw this question: ["Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS" when no such environment variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414699/picked-up-java-options-when-no-such-environment-variable-exists) but it doesn't help with my situation since I'm not using a Razer. Does anybody know what could possibly cause _java_options to be added during the installation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the application HP QuickTest was overriding my java configuration. Deleting that application resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in System Environment Variable and if you have a variable called JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. if you do, rename it.